# C pointer returning data other than the expected contents, but the data remains the same no matter the index accessed?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, struct

I have a 2d array, `const unsigned long test_tileset[n][8]`, which I'm trying to load into a struct.

The struct is defined as:

```
typedef struct DynamicTileset {
    unsigned long **tileset;
    LinkedList* usedTiles;
    short* tilemap;
} DynamicTileset;
```

and I assign the value using the function:

```
DynamicTileset* createDynamicTileset(unsigned long **tileset) {
    DynamicTileset* dynamicTileset = malloc(sizeof(DynamicTileset));
    dynamicTileset->tileset = tileset;
    dynamicTileset->usedTiles = createLinkedList();
    dynamicTileset->tilemap = NULL;
    return dynamicTileset;
}
```

called as:

```
DynamicTileset* title_tileset = createDynamicTileset(test_tileset);
```

And verify that `title_tileset->tileset == test_tileset`.

The problem arises when I try to access any of the tiles from the struct. I can access indices in the original tileset just fine via `test_tileset[i][j]`, but when I try to do the same through `title_tileset->tileset[i][j]`, I get a specific set of seemingly random data every time. I'm guessing I've messed something up with the pointers here, but I can't seem to figure out what. How can I assign one of these tilesets to the struct?

Minimal example:

```
//You likely want to include these in a separate .c file and include the .h, to prevent the error  
//"multiple definitions" from happening when compiling. I do not know if this happens to others
//or if it is simply my compiler.
const unsigned long test_tileset[1][8] = {
    {   0x12345678,
        0x23456789,
        0x3456789A,
        0x456789AB,
        0x56789ABC,
        0x6789ABCD,
        0x789ABCDE,
        0x89ABCDEF
    }
};

typedef struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

typedef struct LinkedList
{
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
    int size;
} LinkedList;

typedef struct DynamicTileset {
    unsigned long **tileset;
    LinkedList* usedTiles;
    short* tilemap;
} DynamicTileset;


struct LinkedList* createLinkedList() {
    struct LinkedList* list = malloc(sizeof(struct LinkedList));
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;
    list->size = 0;
    return list;
}

DynamicTileset* createDynamicTileset(unsigned long **tileset) {
    DynamicTileset* dynamicTileset = malloc(sizeof(DynamicTileset));
    dynamicTileset->tileset = tileset;
    dynamicTileset->usedTiles = createLinkedList();
    dynamicTileset->tilemap = NULL;
    return dynamicTileset;
}

//this should be in the main file
int main() {
    DynamicTileset* title_tileset = createDynamicTileset(test_tileset);

    if (title_tileset->tileset != test_tileset) {
        printf("tileset pointer is wrong");
    }
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
        if (title_tileset->tileset[0][i] != test_tileset[0][i]) {
            printf("first tile is wrong");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Missing headers in your [mre].  typedef for u32, s16 etc.

Comment: `struct Node* createLinkedList()` says you return a `Node *` but you return a `LinkedList *`  If you introduce the typedef why do you use the struct name?

Comment: @AllanWind I've updated the types to common types, and I've fixed the return type (typo copying over function to question). I've only set it as the struct because I was working on debugging the lists, but it still is equivalent to my knowledge, so it shouldn't make any difference? Hopefully that helps!

Comment: The crux of it is probably that your test_tileset is a u32 (*)[8] but in your struct it's a u32 **.

Comment: In` const u32 test_tileset[n][8]` test_tileset is an array of arrays. Your `unsigned long **tileset;`, tileset is a pointer to pointer. Those are two different things. Neither is a replacement for the other. [If you'd turn up your compiler warning settings, it would complain about your attempt to use them as equivalents.](https://godbolt.org/z/e79K8xKTz)

Comment: One main point of a MCVE as linked in the first comment, is, that it is exactly the code you run on your computer to reproduce the problem. Then, the code is just copied here without any changes and without any chance to introduce some typos because they would have shown already when you compile it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the missing headers and typedefs.  Removed the struct name `LinkedList` and used the typedef name in your code.  Then I changed the type of your `test_tileset` to match your use (both u32/unsigned long, and [][] to **).  Added a `const` cast when you compare the const and non-cost types values.  Your code now compiles without warning and prints nothing (success):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
typedef uint32_t u32;
typedef int16_t s16;

const u32 **test_tileset = (const u32 *[]) {
    (u32 []) {
        0x12345678,
        0x23456789,
        0x3456789A,
        0x456789AB,
        0x56789ABC,
        0x6789ABCD,
        0x789ABCDE,
        0x89ABCDEF
    }
};

typedef struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

typedef struct
{
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
    int size;
} LinkedList;

typedef struct DynamicTileset {
    u32 **tileset;
    LinkedList* usedTiles;
    s16* tilemap;
} DynamicTileset;


LinkedList *createLinkedList() {
    LinkedList* list = malloc(sizeof(*list));
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;
    list->size = 0;
    return list;
}

DynamicTileset* createDynamicTileset(const u32 **tileset) {
    DynamicTileset* dynamicTileset = malloc(sizeof(DynamicTileset));
    dynamicTileset->tileset = (u32 **) tileset;
    dynamicTileset->usedTiles = createLinkedList();
    dynamicTileset->tilemap = NULL;
    return dynamicTileset;
}

int main() {
    DynamicTileset* title_tileset = createDynamicTileset(test_tileset);
    if ((const u32 **) title_tileset->tileset != test_tileset) {
        printf("tileset pointer is wrong");
    }
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
        if (title_tileset->tileset[0][i] != test_tileset[0][i]) {
            printf("first tile is wrong");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```